# What crankset fits BH Ultralight RC?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, shifter

This is somewhat related to an issue I had previously posted.

The shop initially said it was the cassette, but after a thorough check-up, the shop told me that the issue is the wear & tear of the crankset (he showed me the worn *teeth*). It makes sense since I haven't changed any of the parts since I purchased the bike. The shifters are also failing, so eventually I'll have to change them as well.

I started searching for *inexpensive* crankset on ebay, but I don't know where to start. There are tons of them, but I have no idea which fits my bike.

Generally speaking, how do I search for the correct crankset for my bike? Does a new crankset come with the correct bottom bracket?

This is my BH Ultralight RC Road Bike:
[image]

Comment: Consider joining [chat]   there's a lot going on here

Comment: Judging from this and your other questions I'd strongly suggest looking for another bike shop. At least check whether you have another one available.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot to unpick, least of all is this was not a cheap bike when new. The specs I have found on the net shows components like SRAM Red 11 and an FSA SLK 386 50/34 crank.  Replacing this with "inexpensive" as you have suggested is not thing you want to do lightly, even if it is an older bike.

If it is just worn teeth, easy and (should be) cheapest option is replacing the chain rings.  I would recommend replacing both chainrings, along with the cassette and chain so you are starting with everything new. If you mix worn and new components the new components wear faster (and you never get the feel of a crisp, new drive line).  The FSA SLK 386 50/34 crankset used a 110mm 4 bolt chainrings, but they are FSA's 'special' (as I understand) Asymmetrical Bolt Spacing, so do check any chainrings you order will fit.  It is likely the only compatible chainrings are premium range product, so you may find a new (or used) crankset, with more standard chainrings provides a cheaper option.

The Bottom bracket on that bike is specified as a (press fit) BB386 (Evo), you will need a BB386 crankset if you replace the entire crankset. If you go this path, any BB386 compatible crankset should work.

Given you have also indicated your shifters are also on the way out, it would be prudent to cost replacing the entire group set, as group sets are often a lot cheaper way to buy components compared to individual items.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know you could change the chainring. At least for now, that seems like the most inexpensive option.

Comment: @rbhat can you clarify details about the crank and groupset in your question? This answer suggests it's a 11 speed SRAM groupset. Your other question made it seem that it's a 10 speed Shimano.

Comment: @user2705196 - I pulled those details from http://www.bikeroar.com/products/bh/ultralight-red-2014/specs. Most other sites indicate SRAM group set for this bike, although I have found a couple of Shimano equipped (105 and Ultegra Di2) lists - all 11speed.  (Edit question to make it clear)